# How to remove the timezone from yfinance data?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I grab data with yfinance package. I convert it into a panda dataframe.
However, I am unable to save the dataframe to excel file.

> ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please
> ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.

This is how the dataframe looks like. It should be 8 columns. Spyder says it has 7 columns.
[image]

Below is my codes:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stock = yf.Ticker("BABA")
# get stock info
stock.info

# get historical market data
hist = stock.history(start="2021-03-25",end="2021-05-20",interval="15m")
hist = pd.DataFrame(hist)

# pd.to_datetime(hist['Datetime'])
# hist['Datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)

hist.to_excel(excel_writer= "D:/data/python projects/stock_BABA2.xlsx")
```

Comment: I am a newbie. Can you show me the code? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the time zone information of `DatetimeIndex` using [`DatetimeIndex.tz_localize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html) , as follows:

```
hist.index = hist.index.tz_localize(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert time zones using `tz_convert()`, in your situation it should work with:

```
hist.index = hist.index.tz_convert(None)
```